# How to use the output of grep in ifelse statement

Tags: unix

I am writing a script where I am grepping for a word and if it is true it should exit script else should continue the script. But my script is not going to else part even when grep output is false.

```
ps -fu rdb1 | grep humor >> humor_chk
grep humor.pl humor_chk | tail -1
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "`date +%D' '%T` Humor is still running. Hence exiting" >> $LOG1
    exit
else
    ls -lrt /a/b/c/ >> files
fi
```

I am getting the output as:
01/19/15 05:54:03 Humor is still running. Hence exiting

Comment: You're testing the success of `tail -1`, not `grep`, because `$?` contains the status of the last command in a pipeline.

Comment: Thank you. I got the error. But the thing is when I  grep humor >> humor_chk, this gives me many number of lines which I don't want to display. So I am using tail -1. Is there anyway I can stop grep displaying all  output lines and only take the output?

Comment: You can use the `-q` option to tell it not to output the matching lines.